# trying to avoid arrow function, but not working correctly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Im trying to avoid the arrow function because I need to support IE11.

Working code on chrome/firefox/edge:

```
reader.onload = (e) => {
  let name = this.files[0].name;
  console.log(name);
};
```

Trying to convert this code into normal function syntax:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
  let name = this.files[0].name;
  console.log(name);
};
```

but now `this.files[0]` is undefined. In the first code block it isn't undefined. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you give a more complete example? What is `reader`? What is `this.files`? Right now there isn't enough information to help.

Comment: this will refer to the event here. You will have to explicitly bind this this using bind() method

Comment: Then you would use `bind` to bind `this` yourself `(function(e) {  ... }).bind(this)`, but for arrow functions you could use babel to transpile your code to an IE11 compatible syntax.

Comment: @t.niese Thanks for this answer, works to bind this